# Visit all routes in React web application in the background without user knowledge/interaction for caching

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, caching, routes

In my web application, the results of the API calls will get cached, once a page is visited. So, if a page is visited for the second time, there will be no load time. So, is there any way to go to all the routes of my site in a users browser when my site is visited, without the knowledge of the user?

I have searched every where. I couldn't find any solution. So, just wanted to know whether is this possible and I am not trying to do anti pattern things.